# ObjectPageLayout inside a Dialog

Tags: sapui5

Can I insert Object Page Layout (for example this https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.uxap.sample.ObjectPageSection/preview) inside a Dialog?

If I try to do it, I see only the anchor bar, not the bottom body.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to disable scrolling on the sap.m.Dialog element to avoid the Dialog from adding content indefinitely. See https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2514